# Pass Variable to Custom Block template file

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I want to create my custom block with custom content in Drupal 8,in start I create  Block with just simple text on it, and work correctly, my Problem is how can I pass my custom variable to it?
I saw some tutorial about it , my Module name is `tcdev` and this is content of `.module` file.

```
function tcdev_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array('tcdev' =>
        array(
            'variables' => array(
                'title' => 'Default title',
                'description' => null
            ),
            'template' => 'block--sliderblock'
        )
    );
}
```

and my `SliderBlock.php`

```
    namespace  Drupal\tcdev\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\block\BlockBase;


/**
 * Provides a 'SliderBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 * id = "slider_block",
 * admin_label = @Translation("Slider Block"),
 * )
 */

class SliderBlock extends BlockBase{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build(){
        return array(
            '#title' => 'my title ',
            '#description' => 'my custom desc'
        );
}
}
```

and finally my template file `block--sliderblock.html.twig`

```
  <h2>My Custom Block{{ title }}-{{ description }}</h2>
```

But Result is only "My Custom Block-" .
**The problem is variables not getting passed to template file,where is my fault?**

appreciate any help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your return array doesn't contain a `#theme` key. So at the moment you aren't using a template file at all.

And you  probably have a mix up between the outer block and theming the content inside of the block. Your template inside has the name tcdev, because that is the name you defined at the top of the array in `*_theme()`, and tcdev.html.twig is where your variables will end up.

Your code would look like the following one.

```
function tcdev_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array('tcdev' =>                  // this is the name of the template
           array(
            'variables' => array(
                'title' => 'Default title',
                'description' => null
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

#### SliderBlock.php

```
namespace  Drupal\tcdev\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\block\BlockBase;


/**
 * Provides a 'SliderBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 * id = "slider_block",
 * admin_label = @Translation("Slider Block"),
 * )
 */

class SliderBlock extends BlockBase{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function build() {
        return array(
            '#theme' => 'tcdev',
            '#title' => 'my title ',
            '#description' => 'my custom desc'
        );
   }
}
```

#### tcdev.html.twig

```
  <h2>My Custom Block{{ title }}-{{ description }}</h2>
```

You wrote that you saw some tutorials about it. Probably this was about two different topics, and you are trying to apply them at the same time.

- [Create custom twig templates from custom module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2640110)
- [Override Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186401)

The custom template in the first link is tcdev.html.twig. What you are trying to do with the method in the second link is for block--sliderblock.html.twig.

Comment: But  `block--sliderblock.html.twig` rendered, the problem is  how pass my variable to it !!!? 
what is you suggest to me according to my code. ?
tnx for your attention

Comment: You want the content of the variables inside a block? Then this is not connected to a block template, because this is for the outside of the block. (`block--sliderblock.html.twig` rendered, because you used the name of a theme suggestion, this would render even if the block would be totally empty, you can try this)

Comment: I tried to change your code to make things clearer, hope this works, didn't debug it.

Comment: I apply your code, rebuild the cache, but still read from `block--sliderblock.html.twig` and nothing passed to it .
I enable  debug info and debug info is `<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/bootstrap/templates/block/block--system-branding-block.html.twig' 
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS: x block--sliderblock.html.twig * block--slider-block.html.twig * block--tcdev.html.twig * block.html.twig -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/gttc_2016/templates/block--sliderblock.html.twig' -->
<h2>Block-</h2>`

Comment: Your variables are not read by `block--sliderblock.html.twig`. This templates works with its own set of variables. (If you want to use this twig you would have to copy it from core or base theme and then you see what variables are inside). Your variables set in the render array of the build function will end up in `tcdev.html.twig`. Did you create this twig file?

Comment: I did, I create `tcdev.html.twig` but it ,clear cache but hit not rendered !!!

Comment: If you still have the wrong `block--sliderblock.html.twig`, your block will never work. You have to remove this twig or put the correct content in it: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/themes/stable/templates/block/block.html.twig

Comment: I found this to work. I had to study the number of bracket enclosures for the array in the tcdev_theme (hook_theme) function above and corrected mine as I had one too many arrays within arrays. Also, I'm curious to see that there is apparently more than one way to pass variables to twig, see also here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260469/pass-variable-from-custom-module-file-to-twig-template-in-d8

Answer (score 4):

So that I found, you want to overwrite a default block template with a custom block (module) template, and then pass your variables to it, first of all you must make sure overwrite your template correctly because seems your current block template outputed from your Theme directory (not module):

```
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/gttc_2016/templates/block--sliderblock.html.twig' -->
```

To do this first you should create a directory called `templates/` in your modules root and then place your template there.

Now let Drupal know you store the template in your module. in `your_module.module` add this function:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'block__my_module' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements',
      'template' => 'block--my-module',
      'base hook' => 'block'
    )
  );
}
```

Finally be careful about where you place your twig file and what you name it. Create a templates directory in your module directory, and replace the `_` in the theme function name with `-`: 
`mymodule-block.html.twig`

Don´t forget to clear the cache.

---

With the help of the answer written by `Nicensin` in this post:
 [Drupal 8 custom block (module) create twig template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643897/drupal-8-custom-block-module-create-twig-template-file)

Comment: What about the variables OP asked for?

Answer (score 1):

I got to this point too. The variables don't seem to be pass to to the block template. I have almost the same code as you, in my case I enabled twig debug and disable cache in services.yml. Even clearing cache I was having this issue but got solved once I activated this config in my dev environment.

```
twig.config:    
# Not recommended in production environments
# @default false
debug: true
# Not recommended in production environments
# @default null
auto_reload: true
```