# pass variable from custom module file to twig template in d8

Tags: 8

How to pass variable from controller to twig template in Drupal-8? 
I have tried to pass variable on module theme folder, but I want to use this variable on global theme?

Answer (score 2):

First create a function that returns the variable, something like this:

```
function my_function() {
return $var_name;
}
```

Then you must create a preprocess function, for the template, like this:

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_TEMPLATE(&$variables) {
  $V_NAME = my_function();
  $variables['v-name'] = $V_NAME;
}
```

Remember to clear the cache.